# Python - How to replace adjacent list elements with a different value

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have been stumped trying to figure how to locate and change the values of the area bordered around a single element of an list without affecting the element values needing to be bordered.

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

BEFORE:

```
[[0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,1,1,0,0],
 [0,1,0,1,0],
 [0,0,1,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0]]
```

AFTER:

```
[[9,9,9,9,0],
 [9,1,1,9,9],
 [9,1,9,1,9],
 [9,9,1,9,9],
 [0,9,9,9,0])
```

I just need to know if I need mainly `for` loops as well as `if/else` statements, or if I need a separate library to get this solved.

Thanks in advance for helping!

Comment: You can solve this in basic python syntax

Comment: This is barely a question... You're kind of just asking how to use python, look around a little first

Comment: It was actually a more for a code golf, because he excludes anything at distance of 2 :) and it's not well phrased but, I thought I'd like to solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And yes , you can just pass with if/else and for loops :

```
 a = [[0,0,0,0,0],
      [0,1,1,0,0],
      [0,1,0,1,0],
      [0,0,1,0,0],
      [0,0,0,0,0]]

 to_replace = 1
 replacement = 9 

 for i in range(len(a)):
     for x in range(len(a[i])):
        if a[i][x] == to_replace:
            for pos_x in range(i-1,i+2):
                for pos_y in range(x-1,x+2):
                    try:
                        if  a[pos_x][pos_y] != to_replace:
                            a[pos_x][pos_y] = replacement
                    except IndexError:
                        print "Out of  list range" #may happen when to_replace is in corners
 for line in a:
     print line 

 #this will give you 
 # [9, 9, 9, 9, 0]
 # [9, 1, 1, 9, 9]
 # [9, 1, 9, 1, 9]
 # [9, 9, 1, 9, 9]
 # [0, 9, 9, 9, 0]
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO FREAKING MUCH!!!! Thank you for understanding my question! Sorry for phrasing it crappily for everyone! Again thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`for` loops and `if/else` statements will suffice.

Comment: Sorry, was just replying directly to his question. He didn't seem to be asking for code.